# What did I do wrong with giving the event to the element?

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events, onchange

I'm trying to use onchange in input, which javascript knows exists, but it's not finding me the event when I try to change something.

Then the console should print me "a" but none of that.

```js
var merende = {
  "ciaccia": {
    "prezzo": 0.8,
    "stock": 11
  },
  "frusta": {
    "prezzo": 1.3,
    "stock": 11
  },
  "pizza": {
    "prezzo": 1.1,
    "stock": 11
  },
  "fagotto": {
    "prezzo": 1.5,
    "stock": 11
  }
}
for (const m in merende) {
  document.getElementById(`qta${m}`).addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    var tot = (e.target.value * merende[m].prezzo).toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).value = `${tot}€`;
    parseFloat(document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).value.split("€")[0]);
  });

  document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log("a");
  })
}
```

```html
<form>
ciaccia <input type=number min=0 max=11 id=qtaciaccia> <input type=text value='0€' readonly id=totciaccia><br>
  frusta <input type=number min=0 max=11 id=qtafrusta><input type=text value='0€' readonly id=totfrusta><br>
  pizza <input type=number min=0 max=11 id=qtapizza><input type=text value='0€' readonly id=totpizza><br>
  fagotto <input type=number min=0 max=11 id=qtafagotto><input type=text value='0€' readonly id=totfagotto><br>
  <input type=submit value=invia&nbsp;lista>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `change` event doesn't trigger when you update `value` programatically. The best option would be to trigger the `change` event yourself:

```
document.getElementById(`qta${m}`).addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    var tot = (e.target.value * merende[m].prezzo).toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).value = `${tot}€`; 
    document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));    
    parseFloat(document.getElementById(`tot${m}`).value.split("€")[0]);
});
```

`dispatchEvent` has good support these days:
https://caniuse.com/?search=dispatchEvent

Comment: Thanks so much for introducing me to this very useful code and sorry for my ignorance lmao xD

Comment: *The best option would be to trigger the change event yourself,* argumably the best option would be to put the logic in an own event which can be called separately and add that event to the listener.

Comment: The best option without rewriting the entire piece of code